# I want to fix one issue during file moving in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I am developing invoice management system with Laravel framework (version 5.3). The system provides a list of documents in a directory on the server. The documents are JPEG or PDF files, they are saved in DB with some metadata. After save a document data in DB, I want to move it to other directory on server.

I tried it by using `File::move($source_path, $target_path)` and `Storage::move($source_path, $target_path)`. But in two case, errors are occurred.

My code is

```
$save_pdf_path = storage_path('invoices').'\\'.$company.'\\'.$date.'\\';
$pdf_name = $invoice_id."_".$user_id.".pdf";
$full_pdf_path = $save_pdf_path.$pdf_name;

File::move(public_path().'\invoice_tmp\\'.$filename, $full_pdf_path);
or
Storage::move(public_path().'\invoice_tmp\\'.$filename, $full_pdf_path);
```

[When use File:move(..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbu9s.jpg)

[When use Storage:move(..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYAxW.jpg)

At last, I tried PHP core function `rename()`, but it is not working too.

Comment: Well, does `F:\websource\docman\public\invoice_tmp\XueToolConf.pdf` exist and have the proper permissions?

Comment: Please do not create edit wars here, Dalca, especially when you are a new user. My edit was a significant improvement, not least in removing the request for "ASAP" attention from volunteers ([related discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)). I would rather you reverted this back to my edit, but in any event I will flag it for a moderator to look at.

Comment: How to give the proper permissions to the folders and files. By the way I think that reason is not because the permission. I am developing on Windows.